# SQLAnywhere default keyword as parameter to parameterized query

Tags: .net, sqlanywhere

How can i send the default keyword as a SAParameter to a stored procedure?

I have a stored procedure called procedureEx that takes 3 parameters and the last one has a default value

I can call it with from sql with call procedureEx('test', 1, **default**)

But how can i do this from .net with parameterized query. In the real code i can get the parameter or not and i want the database to control the default value

```
command.CommandText = "call procedureEx(?,?,?)";
command.Parameters.Add(new SAParameter("", "test");
command.Parameters.Add(new SAParameter("", 1);
command.Parameters.Add(new SAParameter("", default); // <- how do i do this?
```

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you on the way:

```
command.CommandText = "call procedureEx(?,?,?)";
command.Parameters.Add(new SAParameter("", "test");
command.Parameters.Add(new SAParameter("", 1);
command.Parameters.Add(new SAParameter("", SADefault.Value);
```

I tested the code using some dummy data, but it gave me a "Not enough values for host variables" exception, but the code may lead you to the correct solution...